# Using local repositories and setting system properties for them

Tags: scala, sbt

Probably this is very silly question with simple solution...

I read a lot of manuals how to use local repositories but in my case sbt keeps using remote ones.

When I try to override system properties in command line while starting sbt I'm getting following

```
C:\Users\dummy\IdeaProjects\sbt_2021>sbt -Dsbt.repository.config=C:/Users/dummy/.sbt/repositories
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=256m; support was removed in 8.0
Warning: invalid system property 'sbt.repository.config'
[info] Loading project definition from C:\Users\dummy\IdeaProjects\sbt_2021\project
[info] Set current project to sbt_2021 (in build file:/C:/Users/dummy/IdeaProjects/sbt_2021/)
[error] Expected key
[error] Expected '*'
[error] C:/Users/dummy/.sbt/repositories
[error]   ^

C:\Users\dummy\IdeaProjects\sbt_2021>sbt -Dsbt.override.build.repos=true
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=256m; support was removed in 8.0
Warning: invalid system property 'sbt.override.build.repos'
[info] Loading project definition from C:\Users\dummy\IdeaProjects\sbt_2021\project
[info] Set current project to sbt_2021 (in build file:/C:/Users/dummy/IdeaProjects/sbt_2021/)
[error] Not a valid command: true
[error] Not a valid project ID: true
[error] Expected ':' (if selecting a configuration)
[error] Not a valid key: true (similar: run, runner, target)
[error] true
[error]     ^
```

Tried on two differnt computers with sbt version 0.13.7 and 1.0.0

Any help is highly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works well if I specify system properties as part of env variable SBT_OPTS.

In command line it also works but only if I specify sbt system properties in **double quotes**.

PS. When I specify java system properties in command line with `-Dpropery=value` I do not have to use double quotes though.